# How to set multiple items into a GtkSelection for Treeview drag and drop

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

My current project uses a `Gtk.TreeView` to display the contents of a `ListView` with four fields per row, two strings, an `int` and a `boolean`. I'm trying to implement drag and drop rearrangement of rows in the TreeView. I don't want simply to use `TreeView.set_reorderable(True)` for the built-in drag and drop because I want to have some control over the insertion and deletion of data from the model as well as to be able to implement undo/redo of drag and drop operations. I'm using Python 3.2 and PyGObject 3.

The problem I'm now having is figuring out how in my `drag_data_get` method to set the selection data object with the two strings, one int and one `bool` that make up the row to be dragged and dropped. All the example code I've been able to find involves treeviews with a single column with string values that get set into the selection with something like this:

```
def drag_data_get_data(self, treeview, context, selection, target_id, etime):
    treeselection = treeview.get_selection()
    model, iter = treeselection.get_selected()
    data = bytes(model.get_value(iter, 0), "utf-8")
    selection.set(selection.get_target(), 8, data)
```

All my efforts to set the selection object with the data from one of my TreeView rows have failed. The `int` and `bool` values in my model can't be encoded like string values and I can't find any examples of how to set all the values for a multi-column TreeView row into a single selection object. Can anyone point me to some relevant examples or docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode your tuple of 4 values into a single string. An easy way is to use `json` for that:

```
import json
data = ["string", "string2", True, 20]
string_variable = json.dumps(data)
#
# now pass string_variable through drag and drop
#
returned = json.loads(string_variable)
```

You could also use your own encoding scheme if importing `json` is not an option for you.

Please do a careful sanity check on the data you get this way. If you don't, some specially crafted string (passed from another program, say) might crash you program or worse.

Comment: Thanks! Json did just what I needed. Drag and drop is working exactly "as expected." Thanks for the warning on the sanity check - I'm limiting drag and drop to the same widget in the relevant TargetEntry for the drag source and the drag destination. That should prevent nearly all malicious cases, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think that should be safe enough. You should probably mark my answer as accepted, that's the way to say thank you on stack overflow. :-)